# Is there a way to see what image is currently being used as the Mac OS X desktop background / wallpaper?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, desktop-customization, plist

I've downloaded hundreds of wallpapers and have them randomly changing and occasionally want to know what I'm looking at. com.apple.desktop.plist often just has the first file in the folder listed as the background / wallpaper instead of the file currently being displayed. So, short of Google Goggles, how can I tell which image is currently being displayed? Thanks! OS X 10.6.

Comment: Darn. I was going to suggest Google Goggles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
defaults read com.apple.desktop | grep NewImageFilePath
```

the last line shows the location of the previously used image

Comment: Actually I want to grep LastName but with that fix, it works. Thanks!