# Determine location of current wallpaper

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop-customization

I have a very large folder of wallpapers that I have Windows regularly rotating. The folder is too large for it to be practical to find an image simply by thumbnail.  Occasionally, one will come up that I don't like and would like to remove. Is there a way to get the filename of the currently displayed wallpaper(s) so that I could remove them?

In short, my question is [like this one](https://superuser.com/q/285005/240481) but for Windows 8.1 instead of OS X.

Comment: You can hover over the current wallpaper and it should display the filename and location.

Comment: @Ramhound Hover over it in what?

Comment: **Read my comment again.**  I was very specific about what to hover over.

Comment: @Ramhound Like, hover over it in what window?  Hovering over it on my desktop doesn't do anything.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Ramhound If you mean in the "change your desktop background" window, that's not helpful unless there's a way to jump to the current one because, like I've said, there are far too many wallpapers for navigating by thumbnail to be practical.

Comment: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Desktop Background` check there

Comment: @Ramhound OK, yes, that's the one I was referring to as the "change your desktop background" window.  Unless I'm missing something there's no way to jump to the wallpapers currently being used, so I don't think this solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 8.1, when you have multiple images selected, the currently selected image is transcoded you can find the currently selected wallpapers full file path by opening **`RegEdit.exe`** and navigating to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\TranscodedImageCache
```

The image name is in hexadecimal (binary) format. If you double-click, or right click and select "*Modify binary data*" it will open a hex editor.

The right hand column of this editor is the ASCII representation of the unicode characters... this should read the fill filename of the current image. It might look a bit strange as each plain ascii character is suffixed by a "00" (which looks like a "." in the decoded side)... so your filename might look like this in the editor:

```
C.:.\.J.
a.m.e.s.
\.m.y.p.
i.c.t.u.
r.e.s.\.
w.a.l.l.
p.a.p.e.
r.\.s.u.
n.s.e.t.
..j.p.g.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is really cool!  I'll have to try this tonight.

Comment: Sorry, I never got around to trying this till now, but you are correct.  If there are multiple wallpapers you'll have several keys (for instance, if you have multiple monitors).